# C++ string: How to replace unescaped backslash?

Tags: c++, string, escaping, stdstring, backslash

I am reading some log files.  The logs for Windows contain paths like `C:\some\path`.

When I read with `std::getline`, I get a string containing unescaped backslashes.  How can I replace them with forward slashes?

I tried

```
std::replace(str.begin(), str.end(), '\\', '/');
```

but the result looks like `C:somepath` instead of `C:/some/path`.

How do I replace the `\` with `/` or `\\`?

This string is then used to build a JSON object, so not replacing the backslashes results in an invalid JSON object.

Comment: Jerry, Thanks for pointing out the lack of a use case. I have updated the question (see above). I am using the string to build a JSON object, so not replacing the backslashes results in an invalid JSON object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `std::replace` call that you tried is perfectly valid and should do exactly what you want from it, so the only reason for resulting string not to contain any slashes is there were no slashes of any kind to begin with.

I suggest using a debugger to determine what's going on with your string through its whole lifetime

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so this is for conversion to JSON, where backslashes need to be modified somehow or other (apparently conversion to forward slashes is allowable in this case, otherwise you'd need to double the back-slashes to escape them).

Your basic idea should work--simply replacing each `\\` with a `/` should be easy enough.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

int main() { 
    std::string in{"a\\b\\c\\d"};

    std::replace(in.begin(), in.end(), '\\', '/');

    assert(in == "a/b/c/d");

    std::cout << in;
}
```

I'm not sure what problem you encountered--at least for me, this seems to work fine. Of course, this only really makes sense as part of a larger program. If you were going to do this in isolation, `tr` would be entirely sufficient. If you really needed to make it a program, SNOBOL would do the job considerably more easily than C or C++:

```
loop:    INPUT "\" = '/' . OUTPUT     : s(loop)
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape character like newline using `'\n'` or backslash like `'\\'` are only used in literals, i.e. the constant strings and characters in your code. In string or character variables there is no special handling of backslashes.

That's because backslashes in string or character literal constants are handled by the *compiler*, at the time of compilation. Nothing is done at run-time.

So the solution to your problems is really to do nothing at all.

Comment: Actually I am using the contents to build a JSON object. Not doing anything is not an option as the resultant JSON object is then invalid.

Comment: @KarthikKrishnaswamy That's why it's so important to not only ask for help with the solution you have, but to describe the actual problem the solution is for (also known as [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)).